# Change QML Image source from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

if you look at my sample below I can alter the properties of QML objects from my C++ code using QT.

C++

```
QQuickItem* objectimage = quickView->rootObject();
QObject *im = objectimage->findChild<QObject*>("rect");
im->setProperty("color", "red");
```

QML

```
Image {
    objectName: "ima"
    id:pic
    source: "bgnight.png"

    Rectangle{   
        objectName: "rect"
        id:redRect1
        width: 100
        height: 100
        x: 130
        y:230
        color:"transparent"
```

My question is how do you change the source of an image in the same way from C.
I would like to change the background image of QML from C++.

```
Image 
{
    property string src: "bge.png"
    source: src

    objectName: "ima"
    id:pic
}
```

Comment: First, C++ is not C. Then, I'd invert the dependency and bind the image source to a property of a C++ object.

Comment: Are you sure the source is a valid url?

Comment: I see no attempt to change _image source_ in your code example. Did you try to change th source in the same way as you change the color property?

Comment: Yes the image is located in the same directory as the QML file so it loads ok. Just wondering how to change it from within C++. Yes I'm aware C is not C++, sorry for the typo.

Comment: Yes if try to change source it generates a runtime error, changing a qml image source is not as straightforward as changing a object property.

Comment: This snippet it's too few to understand what is happening, you should provide a minimal reproducible example. Said that, I could suggest to use the QQuickImageProvider, you can find here a working sample https://github.com/Daguerreo/QML-ImageProvider

Answer (score 0):

Qt has only C++ api, but you can create separated wrapper library which has C function definition but has C++ implementation

Comment: Oh thanks but my code is c++, sorry for the misunderstanding. So the api is not a problem, just wondering how can i alter the QML image source from C++